# Weird Class Redefinition Error

Tags: c++, templates

I'm having a weird error saying my class is getting redefined, stemming from the declaration of friend in my Node class. Here's my current code:

```
template <class T>
class Node {

private:

    T val;
    Node<T> * next;

public:

    friend class OList;

};
```

Any my other class:

```
template <class T>
class OList {  ------> Error here

private:

    Node<T> * head;
    int size;

public:

    OList();
    OList(const OList<T> &b);
    ~OList();

    clear();
    int size();
    T tGet(int input);
    int count(T input);
    insert (T input);
    remove (T input);
    uniquify(T input);
    Node<T> * returnHead();

};

// Constructs empty list
template <class T>
OList<T>::OList() { ---> Error here
    head = NULL;
    size = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That however gives me an error of explicit-specialization of non-template class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`OList` is not a class, it's a *class template*. You can either friend all specializations of the template:

```
template <typename> friend class OList;
```

or friend a specific specialization:

```
friend class OList<T>;
```

which will require `OList` to already be declared. Put a forward declaration before the definition of `Node`:

```
template <typename> class OList;
```

Comment: Thank you this worked after fixing some other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Also, friend declarations cannot refer to partial specializations.

Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend